# how to export div layer to canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

In my page is div element with transparency, border radius, shadows, etc. **I would like to export this layer to canvas**. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can only export an `img` element to a `canvas`, not an arbitrary element.

Comment: in this case if is possible to export this div layer to png image?

Comment: No, it is not possible. It would be a security problem if you were able to capture any part of the page as an image.